# Mac OS X: Delete my User, or "Current User"

Tags: macos, osx-elcapitan, system-preferences

I have a MacBook Air (with OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.5) that is shared by other users.

I have admin privileges.

I want to delete my "User", however, I cannot do such within "System Preference > Users & Groups", because I can delete "Other Users" but not myself as "Current User".

How can I delete my "User" without affecting "Other Users"?

Comment: Is other accounts admin or not?

Comment: Some are admin and others are not.

Comment: Non-programming questions for OS X are better asked on [su] or [apple.se].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure about my answer but I think you cannot delete user which is logged in. So you should have logged in by another Admin account and remove yours. And If you have not access to other Admin accounts, create another admin user and delete your user when you logged in at new account

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, to create a new admin account to delete my account, then I am now left with another account to delete.

Comment: Yes, I could ask the admin users to delete my User, but it seems to me that I should be able to delete myself. Possibly through some special boot process?

Comment: When you are using an account, some process is running on that; When you try to remove and user, you try to remove threads of that user which delete action would be running at it! It seems the delete action needs to an account to run it.

Comment: Check this link https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203513, at #2 apple says you need to log in by another account. Apple could add a feature to remove current account if another exist at reset. :)

Answer (score 0):

open Terminal and type the following commands, or create .sh file and add them there:

echo "YourPassword" | sudo -S rm -R /Users/YourUser

sudo rm /private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone

sudo dscl . -delete /Groups/YourUser

sudo dscl . -delete /Users/YourUser

Where YourUser could be any user you have already logged in, and "Your Password" (with quotes)  is the same password you use to log in your mac.